# echo DATETIME from SQL SERVER throws 500 error

Tags: php, sql, datetime

I'm running the following code:

```
<?php

include "php/connection.php";

$data = $_GET['data'];

$tsql = "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE CustomerNumber = ".$data;
$result = sqlsrv_query($link, $tsql);

$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);

echo $row['endDate']->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

?>
```

The result set is gathered without issue, the problem is with trying to ouput it as a string as this throws the 500 error, i suspect that's because it's being returned as an object but no matter what i try i can't obtain the data as a string.

The endDate column holds data in this format:

> 2015-04-16 08:22:00.000

The column is 'datetime' format.

EDIT:

Code changed to reflect current code, the echo now shows '1900-01-01 00:00:00 ' but the actual data that should be showing is '2015-04-16 08:22:00.000'

Comment: what does var_dump($row) shows ?

Comment: You could try to do an `print_r` of the data, and you could try without echo'ing something... If you've got then also the 500 error, there's another problem then echoing the object...

Comment: [endDate] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 1900-01-01 00:00:00
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => Europe/Dublin
        )

Comment: set `ReturnDatesAsStrings` to true in your connect options http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628167(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your date is saved as [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) Object and hence its not getting displayed.

Here is an example

```
datetest = new DateTime();
$row = array();
$row["endDate"] = $datetest;
print_r($datetest);
echo "End Date :: ".$row["endDate"]->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

The `print_r()` statement will print something as

```
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2014-04-16 15:04:41 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Asia/Calcutta )
```

which is same in your case.

So in your case

```
   echo $row['endDate']->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: Thanks, that changed the response but the data comes back as: 1900-01-01 00:00:00 whereas the actual data is 2015-04-16 08:22:00.000

Comment: well ur variable dump shows its 1900-01-01 00:00:00, it may be somewhere while the result set is generated in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved by setting ReturnDatesAsStrings to true in my connection options, here's an example:

```
<?php
$serverName = "MyServer";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"AdventureWorks", 'ReturnDatesAsStrings '=> true);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false )
{
   echo "Could not connect.\n";
   die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

sqlsrv_close( $conn);
?>
```